# Поиск по нескольким таблицам в бд

Tags: php, laravel

У нас есть 10 таблиц никак друг с другом не связанных. 10 отдельных сущностей. Вместо id, мы используем uuid и таким способом каждая запись в бд в каждой таблице уникальна. Есть один маршрут написанный на Laravel что то вроде `get('/{uuid}/...` который принимает в качестве параметра этот самый uuid и достает запись.

Способ в принципе рабочий и даже хороший, если нужная нам запись лежит в первой таблице, а что делать если запись будет в 10 таблице?) т.е. мы последовательно пробежимся по 1, 2...и тд.

Такое решение мне предложил тимлид, который работал как он мне сказал на гугл в свое время, надо мол просто индексы создать.

Это реально хорошее и рабочее решение или это мне надо вновь в стажеры идти и учить все заново?

Comment: а каким местом там будет фууллскан? Вы точно понимаете значение этого термина? или выкинув id и добавив uuid, первичным ключом его не сделали? Но при этом фуллскан даже по одной таблице вас не беспокоит? В этом случае тут кругом неадекват, и в стажеры надо вообще всем, с тимлидом во главе

Comment: Кривая здесь архитектура приложения. Почему в запросе нельзя указать *модуль*, к которому он относится, как делают все остальные разработчики мира - загадка.

Comment: Ну не фуллскан, я имел в виду последовательный поиск по всем таблицам, пока не найдем нужную запись

Comment: Вы забыли ещё одно место в вопросе поправить, "надо мол просто индексы создать." Я не знаю, как его интерпретировать в контексте вопроса, кроме как прямое указание на то, что сейчас индексов на uuid нет.

Comment: Может это попытка партиционирования выполненная кривыми руками?

Comment: @u_mulder ну пациент однозначно формулирует, что "таблицы вообще не связаны друг с другом". Хотя я бы конечно не стал безоговорочно доверять этому утверждению. Поскольку да, выглядит именно как попытка партиционирования. Скорее всего тут автор в чем-то недоговаривает, и получаются все эти нестыковки. А нужен ему тот самый банальный "поиск по всем таблицам", где ищется сразу и в товарах, и в пользователях, и в статьях

Comment: Создайте себе таблицу с 2мя полями - uuid, tableName. В нее запихните все uuid и в какой таблице лежит. Тогда вам не придется делать сканирование всех таблиц. Ну и механизм сохранения записей должен быть изменен. А если, все 10 таблиц, имеют одну структуру, то просто объедините все таблицы в одну и постройте индексы под ваши поисковые запросы.

Comment: Парни, таблицы никак не связаны вообще. Суть всей этой затеи что бы вместо 10 эндпоинтов, которые вернут определенную сущность, сделать один мультиэндпоинт, который по uuid будет шариться по 10 таблицам и вытаскивать нужную запись

Comment: Как вариант для ускорения работы можно создать новую таблицу, где `uuid` будет просто индексом (не уникальным) и у него будет значение в виде `varchar` которое будет отсылать на нужную таблицу. А дальше логика простая, PHP смотрит не все 10 таблиц, а одну и исходя из неё отсылает на нужную таблицу.

Comment: А вот uuid должен по задумке быть уникальным что бы нас не спарсили) такие дела

Comment: Эндпойнт-то как раз можно сделать один. просто сущность в нем тоже сделать вариабельной,  `get('/{module}/{uuid}/)`. Но в любом случае это все попахивает костылями и неадекватом.

Comment: ОМГ, все смешнее и смешнее. "чтобы не спарсили". Какой-то детский сад с куличиками. Но зато теперь становится понятной вся затея.

Comment: Вот и я смеюсь сижу, скорее всего последний день в этой компании с такими лидами и их решениями

Comment: решили сделать сквозную нумерацию, то сделайте таблицу общую `uuid,module,mid`, где uuid будет первичным ключом, а mid - целочисленный ключ из внешних таблиц. Опрашивать все 10 таблиц в поисках ключа такое себе занятие. `/module/uuid`, как написано, самый нормальный путь, если нет, то предыдущее - с общей таблицей. Остальное бред проектировщика.

Answer (score -1):

Почитал комменты и ужаснулся. Решение тимлида - не стандартное, но вполне себе рабочее. Не надо создавать отдельную uuid-таблицу и прочие не экологичные решения. Просто в структуру UUID добавьте префикс с ID таблицы и при запросах будет понятно куда искать. А скорее всего ключ к таблице уже там зашит в uuid-e и нужно лишь парсить его на ендпойнте, просто тимлида слили, он обиделся и не рассказал что к чему